# Should I clean the turkey baster used to feed my axolotl?

Tags: feeding, cleaning, amphibians

I use a turkey baster to feed my axolotl blood worms. I can see that there are old worms stuck at the top of the baster. Should I use hot water/bleach to do a proper clean of the baster?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to reuse for yourself, absolutely do a bleach cleaning! Though for sanitary reasons I would purchase a second turkey baster for yourself and keep the one for blood worms solely for your axolotl.

If it is going to stay strictly for your axolotl then a regular cleaning with mild dish soap and hot water is fine (be sure to rinse well!).

Axolotl, like other amphibians, can carry some harmful bacteria, parasites or protozoa that could potentially make us sick if ingested.

Comment: It is going to stay just for the axolotl? Do you think bleach would be too harsh/at risk of leaving residue that may harm the axolotl?

Comment: I would be on thw safe side and wash with mild dish soap or rinse with hot water after each use.